# botocore.errorfactory.InvalidS3ObjectException:

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-rekognition

I am attempting to run multiple images through the AWS system using python code, just a basic for loop. When I run the code I am getting an error. I am able to run  one image but once I attempt to run multiple images I again get an error code.

```
import boto3

if __name__ == "__main__":

bucket='fastlane'
photo=','.join(('test.png',
'test2.png',
'test3.png',
'test4.png',
'test5.png',
'test6.png',
'test7.png',
'test8.png',
'test9.png',
'test10.png',
'test11.png',
'test12.png',
'test13.png',
'test14.png',
'test15.png',
'test16.png',
'test17.png',
'test18.png'))




client=boto3.client('rekognition')


response=client.detect_text(Image={'S3Object': 
{'Bucket':bucket,'Name':photo}})


textDetections=response['TextDetections']
print (response)
print ('Matching faces')
for text in textDetections:
        print ('Detected text:' + text['DetectedText'])
        print ('Confidence: ' + "{:.2f}".format(text['Confidence']) + "%")
        print ('Id: {}'.format(text['Id']))
        if 'ParentId' in text:
            print ('Parent Id: {}'.format(text['ParentId']))
        print ('Type:' + text['Type'])
        print
```

Error code:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 37, in 
    response=client.detect_text(Image={'S3Object':{'Bucket':bucket,'Name':photo}})
  File "/home/Zeus/farcry/AWS/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 320, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/home/Zeus/farcry/AWS/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 624, in _make_api_call
    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.errorfactory.InvalidS3ObjectException: An error occurred (InvalidS3ObjectException) when calling the DetectText operation: Unable to get object metadata from S3. Check object key, region and/or access permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You join all the names into one big string and pass this as the name of the object which won't work unless your s3 object is called `test1.png,test2.png, etc.`

From the docs:

> Name (string) --
>   S3 object key name

You will have to call detect_text for each photo.

What you can do is the following:

```
import boto3

if __name__ == "__main__":

    bucket='fastlane'
    client=boto3.client('rekognition')
    photos= ['test.png',
    'test2.png',
    'test3.png',
    'test4.png',
    'test5.png',
    'test6.png',
    'test7.png',
    'test8.png',
    'test9.png',
    'test10.png',
    'test11.png',
    'test12.png',
    'test13.png',
    'test14.png',
    'test15.png',
    'test16.png',
    'test17.png',
    'test18.png']

    for photo in photos:
        response=client.detect_text(Image={'S3Object':
        {'Bucket':bucket,'Name':photo}})

        textDetections=response['TextDetections']
        print (response)
        print ('Matching faces')
        for text in textDetections:
                print ('Detected text:' + text['DetectedText'])
                print ('Confidence: ' + "{:.2f}".format(text['Confidence']) + "%")
                print ('Id: {}'.format(text['Id']))
                if 'ParentId' in text:
                    print ('Parent Id: {}'.format(text['ParentId']))
                print ('Type:' + text['Type'])
```

Comment: thank you, I did something similar i actually just inserted the                                                                      for loop as so. thanks for the help.                               for photo in photos:


    client=boto3.client('rekognition')

      
    response=client.detect_text(Image={'S3Object':{'Bucket':bucket,'Name':photo}})

Comment: There is one wrong thing with this: you initialize the client on every iteration of the loop. Leave it outside of the loop,  you only.need to initialize it once

Comment: I faced a similar problem like 

***botocore.errorfactory.InvalidS3ObjectException: An error occurred (InvalidS3ObjectException) when calling the CompareFaces operation: Unable to get object metadata from S3. Check object key, region and/or access permissions***

In my case the wrong region was set as a environment variable.